# How can I remove this "Applications" icon which does nothing on clicking either left or right mouse button?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

[image: this image]

As you can see in this image there is an "Applications" button which I want to remove.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It seems you messed sessions. What is the name of the current session (shown on login screen)? Is it named *GNOME FlashBack*? Do you see any changes logging in to *Ubuntu* session?

Comment: There are no changes . I haven't installed any other DE. Just the one which came with the ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and run

```
gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

This should launch a GUI window which lets you manage your installed GNOME shell extensions. Disable (toggle off) "**Applications Menu**" extension from there and relogin.

---

If you are not able to turn that off/on then you should check whether you have turned on Hot corners in Gnome Tweak tool then follow this step.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I had turned off the hot corners activities button and that is why I was unable to access it. Later I turned off the applications menu as suggested by you.